# PHP GD drawing pixel data from array stops mid loop

Tags: php, gd, pixel

I have an array of pixel data in a JSON object. I'm attempting to use PHP to redraw the pixel data to a GD image.

I'm using something like the following (Notice for testing purposes, I've started the index for the loop at 5000, about halfway into the array.)

```
$im = imagecreate($w,$h);
$i=5000;
while($i < count($pixels)){
    $item = $data[$i];
    $rgb = $item['rgb'];
    $pos = $item['pos'];
    $col = imagecolorallocate($im, $rgb[0],$rgb[1],$rgb[2]);
    imagesetpixel($im , $pos[0], $pos[1], $col);
    $i++;
}
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
```

It seems my script is only making it so far down the array before it cuts out and dumps the image out with no error.

Below is the output when I start the array index about halfway thru the length of the array. I get a very small part of the image.

[image]

Is this due to memory? Or a timeout? The page doesn't take long to load or anything...

Comment: What happens if you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, enable error reporting with `ini_set('display_errors', true)`

Comment: you seem to be looping up to the length of the $pixels array, but getting your data from the $data array. The first thing I'd look for is what are the lengths of those two arrays. More generally, when I'm debugging this sort of thing I comment out the header and imagepng lines. Then out can output debugging messages in the loop to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Ok, for anyone else with this problem. Here's the fix.

Use `imagecreatetruecolor` instead of `imagecreate`.

It seems that `imagecolorallocate` can only allocate up to 255 colors when using `imagecreate`. While `imagecreatetruecolor` has no such limitation.

Comment: can you add the data .... `$pixels`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, for anyone else with this problem. Here's the fix. Use `imagecreatetruecolor` instead of `imagecreate`. It seems that `imagecolorallocate` can only allocate up to 255 colors when using `imagecreate`. While `imagecreatetruecolor` has no such limitation.